# Can the default named CSS colors be overridden?

Tags: css, colors

Inspired by [COLORS: A nicer color palette for the web](http://clrs.cc/), I was wondering if there is way to override the default named color definition as defined in the [HTML/CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/) with these new colors.

I am aware that I can create custom CSS rules (and LESS) to define new colors and apply these to which ever elements, however the interest here is for example

```
h1{
    /* #ff0000 is current definition of red, I want to redefine it to #FF4136 */
    color: red;
}
```

### **Update**

I was so inspired by my question, I ended up digging around in the Blink and WebKit source code and from what I can see, these colors are defined within code.

### [Webkit](http://clrs.cc/) Line ~3299

```
static const ColorValue colorValues[] = {
    { CSSValueAqua, 0xFF00FFFF },
    { CSSValueBlack, 0xFF000000 },
    { CSSValueBlue, 0xFF0000FF },
    { CSSValueFuchsia, 0xFFFF00FF },
    { CSSValueGray, 0xFF808080 },
    { CSSValueGreen, 0xFF008000  },
    { CSSValueGrey, 0xFF808080 },
    { CSSValueLime, 0xFF00FF00 },
    { CSSValueMaroon, 0xFF800000 },
    { CSSValueNavy, 0xFF000080 },
    { CSSValueOlive, 0xFF808000  },
    { CSSValueOrange, 0xFFFFA500 },
    { CSSValuePurple, 0xFF800080 },
    { CSSValueRed, 0xFFFF0000 },
    { CSSValueSilver, 0xFFC0C0C0 },
    { CSSValueTeal, 0xFF008080  },
    { CSSValueTransparent, 0x00000000 },
    { CSSValueWhite, 0xFFFFFFFF },
    { CSSValueYellow, 0xFFFFFF00 },
    { CSSValueInvalid, CSSValueInvalid }
};
```

### [Blink](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/) ~ Line 157

### Update 2

There may some hope for the future. FireFox Nightly build includes the concept of a [CSS-variable](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/12/css-variables-in-firefox-nightly/). Although a vendor specific at this point, it 'almost' is related to my question. The related W3C specification : [CSS Custom Properties for Cascading Variables Module Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/) - see Example 4

Comment: no i dont think so....beside doing weird acrobatics with javascript that parses the stylesheet search for colors, find compatible html counterpart colors and replace them to it.

Comment: @abhitalks - I disagree, those are talking about variables and custom colors which can be achieved using a css processor such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

Comment: Hmmmm.. ok... fair enough. removing the earlier comment.

Comment: Why it would not be a new feature in CSS3? If it would, then that would be great....

Comment: if I understood correctly, you will need to target the H1 of an element / div or what ever and you can override it. eg. #myDiv h1 { color}... Ok I miss understood the question. I will keep this just in case someone finds it useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, these color keywords are pre-defined and there is no way to override their color mappings from outside the browser. This applies to *all* named color keywords defined in the spec that you link to, including the basic set of CSS keywords, the X11/SVG keywords and the deprecated system colors (although of course, system colors are taken from the system palette).

You won't be able to query computed styles of DOM elements and replace them on the fly either, because computed color values are always `rgb()` or `rgba()` triplets, even if the cascaded value is the keyword. This is stated in the spec that you link to:

> - The computed value for basic color keywords, RGB hex values and extended color keywords is the equivalent triplet of numerical RGB values, e.g. six digit hex value or rgb(...) functional value, with an alpha value of 1.

In your example CSS rule, the computed `color` of `h1` elements would be `rgb(255, 0, 0)`, not `red`. You cannot distinguish `#ff0000` or `red` from `rgb(255, 0, 0)` in that case, which can pose problems if you're specifically only targeting the `red` keyword.

You could parse and modify the stylesheet directly using a script, but CSS parsing isn't easy. You have to account for shorthand declarations, URLs (e.g. `background: red url(redimg.png) center center no-repeat;`), and so on and so forth. That's probably out of the scope of your question.

Custom properties only allow you to specify a cascading variable in place of a keyword as a value. You won't be able to modify existing pre-defined keywords with custom properties, so you'd still have to replace every occurrence of `red` with something like `var(red)` where the  `var-red` property corresponds to a user-defined red.

Comment: That seem to be exactly what my code digging has found, but I've still got some hope here about a possible workaround.