# Specify numeric value for named colour in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm thinking this is impossible but on the off chance I missed something, is it possible to override the value of named colours?

In other words I have an html page with style="background-color:red;" in it, would it be possible to specify that it use #FA5858 instead of the default #FF0000?

I don't wish to edit the HTML file as it is generated automatically from a few different processes and there is historic data I don't want to lose.

Comment: The client's browser reads & determines the colour to be displayed. Search and change the processes that generate the files to output `background-color:#FA5858;` instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the default named CSS colors be overidden?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036884/can-the-default-named-css-colors-be-overidden) (although note that I only just added the word "named" to the title as it didn't appear in the question prior to this, only in my answer to it)

Answer (score 0):

No, `red` is strictly defined `#f00` and you can´t change it.

But you can use one of CSS preprocessors (eg. LESS, SASS) and work with `$red` variable defined to your `#fa5858`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no.

In CSS, some colors have defined names. They can't be changed.

However, if you use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or other style languages based on CSS, you can do this (almost).

Example in SASS:

```css
$red: #FA5858; /* define variable $red to #FA5858 */

a {
    color: $red; /* use value of variable $red */
}
```

If you want to do this, you can quite easily create a script to convert the color names to variable names. For example, in JavaScript:

```javascript
var css = "a { color: red; }";
var sass = css.replace(/\bred\b/g, "$red");

alert(sass); // a { color: $red; }
```