# Is it possible to redefine named colors in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm using named colors in CSS, e.g. `background-color: red` and would like to use a different tone of red. Is it possible to overwrite the definition of `red, olive, brown, ...` without having to replace the color-word with a Hex or RGB value?

Comment: Not sure if adding the specific `rgb` or `hex` into a `variable` and then calling it wherever needed is what you're looking for (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties)?

Comment: Use SCSS colour variables. Not sure why you don't want to use hex values though?

Answer (score 1):

there is var in css 
var(--colorName) that you can use

```
background-color : var(--colorName)
```

and to define:

```
:root{
--colorName: coral;
}
```

see this article https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to redefine the color code of 'coral' in your case. Currently ```Coral / #ff7f50 hex color``` but should be ```Coral / #ff7123 hex color```

Comment: @JoshuaBeckers to his example: `:root { --coral: #whateverHexYouWant; }`, then call it with `.classname { color: var(--coral); }`

Comment: I have existing CSS/JS code that where I wanted to avoid changing all the color names into codes. This here answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036884/can-the-default-named-css-colors-be-overridden

Comment: I wouldn't advise to change the color of the Webkit.
but if you are intersted to have a var system maybe you should look into CSS framwork, Tailwind or use SCSS : 
$colorBeige: #888777; 
background-color: $colorBeige;